# Tidyr equivalent for transpoing rows/columns and promoting first row (first column of original dataframe) as header?

Tags: r, tidyr

Is there a `tidyr` equivalent way of doing this?  What I have works, but I'm just trying to learn the `tidyr` functions.  Spent about an hour trying to coerce chatGPT into showing me how to do it and nothing worked.  I have it broken out into multiple steps just to help me troubleshoot. I will eventually recombine into one step using pipes...

Note: The dataframe itself is pretty massive with 56000 rows and 1000 columns. I don't have a way to share it so including head() output below. I'm not sure what the minimum information needed is to help.

```
# Step 1: Create the key column
temp1 <- BRes3 %>%
  mutate(key1 = paste(Group, n, sep = "-"))

# Step 2: Remove unnecessary columns
temp2 <- temp1 %>%
  select(key1, everything(), -mean, -`mean CI`, -sdev, -UCI, -LCI, -CIR, -n, -Group)

# Step 3: Transpose the data and set column names
temp3 <- setNames(data.frame(t(temp2[-1])), temp2$key1)
```

Structure of data frame at step2:

```
> head(temp2[1:5])
     key1             est1             est2             est3             est4
X2 X1.A-2        10.799982        10.304256         10.20124         9.550119
X3 X1.A-3 10.3659866666667        10.465434 11.1673413333333 10.8014426666667
X4 X1.A-4        10.679331        10.781562        10.025603       10.1510665
X5 X1.A-5       11.4224648       11.6025256       10.5983192        11.618744
X6 X1.A-6 10.1707603333333 11.0518533333333        10.416587         10.18374
X7 X1.A-7        10.590982 10.6979774285714 10.6989508571429 10.1854577142857
```

Desired final structure:

```
> head(temp3[1:5])
        X1.A-2           X1.A-3     X1.A-4     X1.A-5           X1.A-6
est1 10.799982 10.3659866666667  10.679331 11.4224648 10.1707603333333
est2 10.304256        10.465434  10.781562 11.6025256 11.0518533333333
est3  10.20124 11.1673413333333  10.025603 10.5983192        10.416587
est4  9.550119 10.8014426666667 10.1510665  11.618744         10.18374
est5 10.800006         9.970464 11.5241455 11.6005004 10.9990463333333
est6  12.30192 11.0995906666667  10.449673 10.2591216 10.7492366666667
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all columns except `key1` are the same class (`numeric` here), the we can do (starting with `temp2`):

```r
library(tidyr)
temp2 |>
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric)) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = "key1")
# # A tibble: 4 × 7
#   name  `X1.A-2` `X1.A-3` `X1.A-4` `X1.A-5` `X1.A-6` `X1.A-7`
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 est1     10.8      10.4     10.7     11.4     10.2     10.6
# 2 est2     10.3      10.5     10.8     11.6     11.1     10.7
# 3 est3     10.2      11.2     10.0     10.6     10.4     10.7
# 4 est4      9.55     10.8     10.2     11.6     10.2     10.2
```

---

Data

```r
temp2 <- structure(list(key1 = c("X1.A-2", "X1.A-3", "X1.A-4", "X1.A-5", "X1.A-6", "X1.A-7"), est1 = c(10.799982, 10.3659866666667, 10.679331, 11.4224648, 10.1707603333333, 10.590982), est2 = c(10.304256, 10.465434, 10.781562, 11.6025256, 11.0518533333333, 10.6979774285714), est3 = c(10.20124, 11.1673413333333, 10.025603, 10.5983192, 10.416587, 10.6989508571429), est4 = c(9.550119, 10.8014426666667, 10.1510665, 11.618744, 10.18374, 10.1854577142857)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X2", "X3", "X4",  "X5", "X6", "X7"))
```

Comment: A note for the OP: you could start with the output from step 1 here because the unwanted columns will be dropped during the `pivot_wider` since `id_cols` is set. So you do not need the `select` statement. Though to do this it might be safer to set `cols = starts_with("est")`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
data.table::transpose(df, make.names = 'key1', keep.names = 'est')

   est    X1.A-2   X1.A-3   X1.A-4   X1.A-5   X1.A-6   X1.A-7
1 est1 10.799982 10.36599 10.67933 11.42246 10.17076 10.59098
2 est2 10.304256 10.46543 10.78156 11.60253 11.05185 10.69798
3 est3 10.201240 11.16734 10.02560 10.59832 10.41659 10.69895
4 est4  9.550119 10.80144 10.15107 11.61874 10.18374 10.18546
```

---